# SQL Server force only RowLock

Tags: sql-server, locking

I'm facing a big problem on updating rows of a table which stores counters. I'm using a transaction to get the value and update it, and I try to lock only the row of the counter affected to avoid locks and deadlocks but it's not working.

That's a reduced sample of the code where I can reproduce the error:

```
CREATE TABLE _COUNTERS_ 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    CODE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CVALUE INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        ID ASC,
        CODE ASC,
        CVALUE ASC
    ) WITH (ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF)
)

INSERT INTO _COUNTERS_ (CODE, CVALUE) VALUES ('C1', 0)
INSERT INTO _COUNTERS_ (CODE, CVALUE) VALUES ('C2', 0)
```

I'm trying to force to avoid PageLocks with the index definition.

In SQL Server Management Studio, I execute this statement in a window. I use the first query to lock the COUNTER to avoid other threads o servers (the app is multithread and installed on a farm so I can't use .NET locks) get a bad number num while it's near to update:

```
-- Window 1
BEGIN TRAN 
SELECT *
FROM _COUNTERS_ this_ WITH (
        UPDLOCK,
        ROWLOCK
        )
WHERE this_.CODE = 'C1'
UPDATE _COUNTERS_ SET CVALUE = 1 WHERE ID = 1
```

In an another SQL Server Management Studio window, I query the locked resources:

```
-- Window 2
SELECT  L.request_session_id AS SPID,
--        DB_NAME(L.resource_database_id) AS DatabaseName,
        O.Name AS LockedObjectName,
        P.object_id AS LockedObjectId,
        L.resource_type AS LockedResource,
        L.request_mode AS LockType,
        ST.text AS SqlStatementText,       
--        ES.login_name AS LoginName,
--        ES.host_name AS HostName,
        TST.is_user_transaction as IsUserTransaction,
        AT.name as TransactionName,
        CN.auth_scheme as AuthenticationMethod
FROM    sys.dm_tran_locks L
        JOIN sys.partitions P ON P.hobt_id = L.resource_associated_entity_id
        JOIN sys.objects O ON O.object_id = P.object_id
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions ES ON ES.session_id = L.request_session_id
        JOIN sys.dm_tran_session_transactions TST ON ES.session_id = TST.session_id
        JOIN sys.dm_tran_active_transactions AT ON TST.transaction_id = AT.transaction_id
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections CN ON CN.session_id = ES.session_id
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(CN.most_recent_sql_handle) AS ST
WHERE   resource_database_id = db_id()
ORDER BY L.request_session_id
```

[image: Locked resources]

In a third window I execute the following statement:

```
-- Window 3
BEGIN TRAN 
SELECT *
FROM _COUNTERS_ this_ WITH (
        UPDLOCK,
        ROWLOCK
        )
WHERE this_.CODE = 'C2'
UPDATE _COUNTERS_ SET CVALUE = 2 WHERE ID = 2
```

And the first select keeps waiting until I commit the first transaction.

Is it possible to keep every counter totally isolated in selects and updates?

Some additional considerations about the real environment:

- SQL Server 2012
- The table has 107 rows
- The first transaction (Window 1) only show one row on the locks query as opposed to the two rows of the screenshot I've posted.
- The second transaction (Window 3), can do the first select without waiting and it keeps waiting on the UPDATE statement.
- A deadlock (only in real environment) is reproduced executing first the two select queries and then the two updates, it can't be reproduced with the posted sample because the first select locks full table.

**UPDATE 2020-03-02**
Using the index by code (as commented by @larny or posted by @esat) solves the problem on the sample I've posted but in my real table (VISUALSEGCONTADORES), the select is not using the new index:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_VSGCONTADORES ON VISUALSEGCONTADORES (VSC_ALIAS ASC) WITH (ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF);
```

Here the plan of one of the selects (the other uses the same index): https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJRWtocE8

And the real table structure (with the special clustered index):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VISUALSEGCONTADORES](
    [VSC_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VSC_Alias] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [VSC_Objeto] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VSC_Serie] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [VSC_Contador] [decimal](20, 8) NOT NULL,
    [VSC_Enabled] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [USR_Id_FC] [int] NOT NULL,
    [USR_Id_FM] [int] NOT NULL,
    [VSC_FC] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [VSC_FM] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LOG_ID_FC] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [LOG_ID_FM] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [LOG_FC] [datetime] NULL,
    [LOG_FM] [datetime] NULL,
    [OFI_ID] [int] NULL,
    [VSC_OFICODE] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TRN_Aud_Id_FC] [int] NULL,
    [TRN_Aud_Id] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_VISUALSEGCONTADORES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [VSC_Alias] ASC,
    [VSC_OFICODE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The real queries are the following:

```
-- Window 1
BEGIN TRAN 
SELECT *
FROM VISUALSEGCONTADORES this_ WITH (
        UPDLOCK,
        ROWLOCK
        )
WHERE this_.VSC_Alias = 'VSG_UltimoCodEXP' AND VSC_OFICODE = 0
UPDATE VISUALSEGCONTADORES SET VSC_Contador = 9910 WHERE VSC_Id = 142
```

The other window

```
-- Window 3
BEGIN TRAN 
SELECT *
FROM VISUALSEGCONTADORES this_ WITH (
        UPDLOCK,
        ROWLOCK
        )
WHERE this_.VSC_Alias = 'VSG_ULTIMAMATRIZ' AND VSC_OFICODE = 0

UPDATE VISUALSEGCONTADORES SET VSC_Contador = 1273 WHERE VSC_Id = 121
```

Defined by business, sometimes the queries are with VSC_OfiCode and sometimes don't, but I've tested both and throws the same results.

The locked resources:
[image]

Comment: Does `_COUNTERS_` have any other indexes on it? You reference `WHERE this_.CODE = 'C1'` in the first SQL statement, which is going to require a scan at least, if there aren't any other than the Clustered PK. Also, what is purpose is this counter trying to serve? I *assume* it isn't trying to replace a `SEQUENCE`; but if it is, I recommend against the design you have. SQL Server has functionality to handle what you are after, and it is much better at it.

Comment: THINK about your schema. If ID is an identity, does it make any reasonable sense to declare the primary key as <ID, CODE, CVALUE>? Based on your sql, it seems that your natural primary key is just CODE. However, the first Window 1 snippet you select by CODE but you update by ID. Is there some assumption in both this sample and your actual system where you equate the 2 based on this assumption?

Comment: As @Larnu says, creating index on CODE solves the problem! I'll do more tests but I think that it's the point!

Comment: I was seriously not expecting the problem to be that trivial... /headdesk

Comment: @Larnu it's working on the fake _COUNTERS_ table I've created to reproduce it in a lighter environment, but not in my table, I'll update the question to reflect the latest clues.

Comment: You didn't really address the rest of my comment though, @Marc . Like i said, if you are trying to emulate to functionality of a `SEQUENCE`, then use `SEQUENCE`. If not, describe what the goal of this `COUNTERS` table is.

Comment: @Larnu, yes I've a project to improve the legacy counter's mechanism, I'll study to use sequences but it's not trivial, and the lost of rollbacks is a disadvantage that has a lot of weight. I would to solve the problem faster, perhaps it's impossible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Window3** query tries to acquire exclusive lock-on a row which is still reading by the **Window1**.
If you analyze the execution of the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM _COUNTERS_ this_ WITH (
        UPDLOCK,
        ROWLOCK
        )
WHERE this_.CODE = 'C2'
```

[image]

So this query will wait until the commit or rollback of the Window1 query. If you try to execute Window3 update individually, it will be executed

```
-- Window 3
BEGIN TRAN 
--SELECT *
--FROM _COUNTERS_ this_ WITH (
--        UPDLOCK,
--        ROWLOCK
--        )
--WHERE this_.CODE = 'C2'
UPDATE _COUNTERS_ SET CVALUE = 2 WHERE ID = 2
```

On the other hand, if we handle this problem we can create a non-clustered index on the **CODE** column or we can change the query like the below

```
--Window3
BEGIN TRAN 
SELECT *
FROM _COUNTERS_ this_ WITH (
        UPDLOCK,
        ROWLOCK
        )
WHERE this_.CODE = 'C2' AND ID=2
UPDATE _COUNTERS_ SET CVALUE = 2 WHERE ID = 2
```

This two option provides to avoid cluster index scan

Comment: Thanks, it's the same that points @Larnu on a question's comment, and in the _COUNTERS_ table I've created is working fine (the index) but on my real table, the query don't use the index, I'll update the question,

Comment: @Marc  Maybe you can upload the execution plan of the window1 or window3 query. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ .  So we can think of this.

Comment: @Marc The query uses the clustered index seek. In my thought, window1 and window3 have to work at the same time.

Comment: I see it, and both queries work together (i wrote on my post on differences between real and fake environment) but the first update (window1 or window3 is locked), and the next one throws a Deadlock and the is rollbacked.

Comment: Could you update the window1 and window3 queries with the real update queries?  The problem started to become clearer.

Comment: @Marc I created your real tables and generated 100,000 rows for it. The execution plan of the update query has changed. SQL Server has offered the following index script and I created the index and window1 and  then window3 query run at the same time. This is the index script which ı have created -> "CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NewIndex]
ON [dbo].[VISUALSEGCONTADORES] ([VSC_Id])"

Comment: Ohhhh, thanks, how I can be so dumb? There was no index over the ID, that was the filter of the UPDATE, thanks a lot @esat! I check your question as response, because the original problem was solved with your response. The problem was that I didn't reproduce the environment well!